# Ef Core TPH & relations Issue

Tags: asp.net-core, foreign-keys, entity-framework-core, entity-relationship, tph

I Have This Tables & class :

```
   public abstract class ProductBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
} 
public class Product:ProductBase
{

    public virtual ICollection<ProductType> Types { get; set; } = new HashSet<ProductType>();
    public virtual ICollection<OnlineStock> OnlineStocks { get; set; } = new HashSet<OnlineStock>();
}
public abstract class ProductTypeBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    protected virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
public class ProductType:ProductTypeBase
{
    public new Product Product
    {
        get { return base.Product; }
        set { base.Product = value; }
    }
}
public class OnlineStock:ProductTypeBase
{
    public new Product Product
    {
        get { return base.Product; }
        set { base.Product = value; }
    }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductTypePicture> Pictures { get; set; } = new HashSet<ProductTypePicture>();

}
```

When i want to add new product with producttype .

```
Context.Porduct.Add(new Product
    {
     Types=new List<ProductTypes>
          {
             new ProductTypes {Quantity=8}
          }
    })
```

ef error : "Unable to cast object of type 'ProductType' to type 'OnlineStock'."

and also i have this config :

```
entityBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(x=>x.Types).WithOne(x=>x.Product).HasForeignKey("ProductId");
        entityBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(x=>x.OnlineStocks).WithOne(x=>x.Product).HasForeignKey("ProductId");
```

Comment: Also don't use `new`, use `virtual` and `override`. `new` only hides the member, when you call the property on the base type you get the other property. You'd be well advised to start with a beginner book or tutorial on inheritance before starting more complex projects. And in your case, both newing and overriding of the `Product` property is unnecessary

Comment: Is this the **actual** code or just something you typed for the question? Cause it appears that the exception doesn't match the given code above

Comment: @Tseng Actual Code Just have more property .but navigation properties not change .

Comment: I think we need to see the `DbSet<...> Porduct` (which shold have be been named Products)

Comment: I tried reproducing above but I got no error. Your code for adding new record does not compile either. Did you actually run this code? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I Solved This isssue Temporary.

```
    var NP=new Product(); 
    Context.Porduct.Add(NP);
    Context.saveChanges();
    NP.Types.Add(new ProductTypes
              {
                  Quantity=8
              });
   Context.saveChanges();
```